# Presto SQL - Count 1 for each row after condition and negative 1 before

Tags: sql, presto

I have data like this:

```
date         group   state value
2018-01-01   A       A        20
2018-01-02   A       A        0
2018-01-03   A       A        0
2018-01-04   A       B        70
2018-01-05   A       B        0
2018-01-06   A       B        80
```

I would like to count each date by 1 going forward from moving from state A to state B where the first date = 0 and the day after = 1 so on.  I would also like the dates prior to be counted by -1.  I would also like to do this by the group column to ensure that each group has a separate count.

This would be the output:

```
date         group   state value  count
2018-01-01   A       A        20 -3    
2018-01-02   A       A        0  -2
2018-01-03   A       A        0  -1
2018-01-04   A       B        70  0
2018-01-05   A       B        0   1
2018-01-06   A       B        80  2
```

I've tried something like this:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY group, state ORDER BY date)
```

However I end up with a column of 1's.

Comment: Will there always be only two `state`s? And how to decide which `state` gets negative values? The "lower" valued one gets the negative ones? Or do you want to specify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to use `SUM` with *window function*.

this sqlfiddle is SQL-server, but `prestodb` also support *windows function*, just let `DATEDIFF` convert to [date_diff](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html) function.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  date DATE,
    [group] VARCHAR(50),
    state VARCHAR(50),
    value INT
);




INSERT INTO T VALUES ('2018-01-01','A','A' ,20);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('2018-01-02','A','A' ,0);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('2018-01-03','A','A' ,0);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('2018-01-04','A','B' ,70);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('2018-01-05','A','B' ,0);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('2018-01-06','A','B' ,80);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *,SUM(CASE 
             WHEN state = 'B' AND MINDT = date  THEN 0
             WHEN  state = 'B' THEN 1
             else -1 end
            ) OVER(PARTITION BY [group], state ORDER BY 
                   CASE WHEN state = 'B' THEN date_diff(day,MAXDT,date)
                        WHEN state = 'A' THEN date_diff(day,date,MINDT)
                   END)  count
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
         MAX(date) over(PARTITION BY [group], state ORDER BY date desc) MAXDT,
         MIN(date) over(PARTITION BY [group], state ORDER BY date) MINDT
  FROM T
) tt
order by date
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/907ff/18/0)**:

```
|       date | group | state | value |      MAXDT |      MINDT | count |
|------------|-------|-------|-------|------------|------------|-------|
| 2018-01-01 |     A |     A |    20 | 2018-01-03 | 2018-01-01 |    -3 |
| 2018-01-02 |     A |     A |     0 | 2018-01-03 | 2018-01-01 |    -2 |
| 2018-01-03 |     A |     A |     0 | 2018-01-03 | 2018-01-01 |    -1 |
| 2018-01-04 |     A |     B |    70 | 2018-01-06 | 2018-01-04 |     0 |
| 2018-01-05 |     A |     B |     0 | 2018-01-06 | 2018-01-04 |     1 |
| 2018-01-06 |     A |     B |    80 | 2018-01-06 | 2018-01-04 |     2 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/adaf3/30) logic :

```
SELECT t.*,
       ( case when ( group_ = 'A' and state = 'B' ) then
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY group_, state ORDER BY date)
         else
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY group_, state) -
          COUNT(1) over (PARTITION BY group_, state) 
         end ) - 1 as count
  FROM tab t;
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one transition, I would recommend:

```
select t.*,
       (seqnum - max(case when state = 'B' then seqnum end) over ()) as counter
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

In other words, generate a sequential series.  Then subtract the value where `B` first appears.